# Write PHP file with PHP

Tags: php, file, fopen, fwrite

i want to post a username to a PHP File. Then i want that the Username will be implemented in a PHP File which i will write in my script.

But its not working? And how do i implement the POST username in the string on $Line 5? And i want to write every line as single line, its putting all together i think. I Guess it would be easier to copy the file, and implement there the Post but i dont know how to do that.

Token Infos are not the real one ;)

```
$username = $_POST["username"];


//twilio tokenlines
$Line0 = "<?php";
$Line1 = "include '../Services/Twilio/Capability.php'";
$Line2 = "$accountSid = '3763876534876584'; ";
$Line3 = "$authToken  = '4765784365874365'; ";
$Line4 = "$capability = new Services_Twilio_Capability($accountSid, $authToken); ";
$Line5 = "$capability->allowClientIncoming("HERE I WANT TO STAND MY POST"); ";
$Line6 = "$capability->allowClientOutgoing('746357846358764387564387'); ";
$Line7 = "$token = $capability->generateToken(); ";
$Line8 = "echo $token;";
$Line9 = "?>";  


$tokenfile = fopen("${username}.php", 'w'); 
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line0); 
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line1); 
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line2);
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line3);
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line4);   
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line5); 
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line6); 
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line7); 
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line8);
fwrite($tokenfile,$Line9);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens (or does not happen)?

Comment: Its not creating the file. When i remove the post, upload it to my webspace and execute the script its not creating the file either.

Comment: syntax check gives me 

`PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in your code on line 2
$Line0 = "<?php";``

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple lines just by appending `\n` at the end of each string.

```
$Line0 = "<?php\n";
```

Don't forget to call

```
fclose($tokenfile)
```

-- only then the contents are guaranteed to be written to disk.

Answer (score 1):

**Semicolon**

```
$Line1 = "include '../Services/Twilio/Capability.php'";
```

=>

```
$Line1 = "include '../Services/Twilio/Capability.php'; ";
                                                     ^
```

---

**Escape**

```
$Line5 = "$capability->allowClientIncoming("HERE I WANT TO STAND MY POST"); ";
```

=>

```
$Line5 = "$capability->allowClientIncoming(\"HERE I WANT TO STAND MY POST\"); ";
                                           ^                             ^
```

---

Add **[`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-sapi)** to end of each line.

```
$Line1 = '...'.PHP_EOL;
$Line2 = '...'.PHP_EOL;
...
```

---

And also **convert all `"` to `'`** because it translates $abc and we don't want it.

Comment: done everything but its giving me syntax error:
PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE) in your code on line 2
$Line1 = 'include '../Services/Twilio/Capability.php';\n'.PHP_EOL;

Comment: remove \n. PHP_EOL will do the \n job for you. @mav

Comment: @mav did it help you? you can choose the answer which helped you as the best.